# Sonar raises - "Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to false" for applicationContext.getBean() method

Tags: spring, sonarqube

Spring's ApplicationContext.getBean() method can return null.

An example for this: [Why is applicationContext.getBean(beanName) returning null, when it clearly exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55408164/why-is-applicationcontext-getbeanbeanname-returning-null-when-it-clearly-exis)

But as per sonar, it can never return null.
Sonar complains - Change this condition so that it doesn't always evaluate to false.

Here is the sample code.

```
        if (context.getBean(myClazz.class) != null) {   // Sonar warning here
```

Is it a false positive case of Sonar or getBean method can never return null?

if it's a false positive, Is there any way I can get around with this warning?

Answer (score 1):

Sonar flagging the null check is correct. because the `context.getBean(beanclass)` will throw `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` if no bean of the given type was found. So the null check isn't useful.

The getBean(beanClass) method is coming from [BeanFactory](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.java), which has documented this behaviour.